# How to import local bare repo to Gogs?

Tags: gogs

I have a few bare Git repos on a host. Later I installed Gogs on same host. I configured it to use the exact same folder for storing repositories, where my bare repos are already residing.

How can I import them? I does not need to "import" anything in fact. I just want Gogs to recognize their existence.

Answer (score 1):

I moved my repositories from one gogs-instance to another gogs-instance. But this should work with github, gitlab or other services as well.

Mirror the source repository to a bare git repo:

```
git clone --mirror git@source-gogs:project.git
```

Push the local bare git repo as mirror to the new destination repo:

```
cd project.git
git push --mirror git@dest-gogs:project.git
```

Note: Do not use `git push --mirror` if you did not clone the repo with `git clone --mirror`. Also, `git clone --mirror` is preferred over `git clone --bare` as it will clone all git notes and attributes as well.